# I want to find the depreciation using colSums

Tags: r

I have a table (let's name it development.costs), as below:

1 2 3 4
4 5 6 7
8 9 1 2

Each column represents a year.

I want to create another table (let's name it depreciation.costs) with the same dimensions such that:
   in each row, each element of each column is equal to:

```
         0.4*[(Sum of all elements of that row of the development.costs table up until the year of the element) - (Sum of all elements of that row of the depreciation.costs table up until one year before)]
```

so I want to create a table

a b c d
e f g h
i j k l

such that e.g. c =0.4*[(1+2+3) - (a+b)]

the code I managed to write is

```
for (y in Years)
{depreciation.costs[y, ] <- 0.4*(colSums(development.costs[1:y], )-colSums(depreciation.costs[1:(y-1), ]))}
```

where Years <- 1:4

but this is wrong since the system gives me the error

Error in colSums(depreciation.rate[, 1:(y - 1)]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

many thanks for any feedback

Comment: What does element `a` equal in your results? In fact, it's probably helpful to just provide the full desired results for `a` through `l`.

Comment: The error is raised, because R implicitly converts your matrix to a vector in the first iteration of the for loop. Check e.g. development.costs[,1]. To prevent this, add drop = FALSE when subsetting a matrix, development.costs[,1, drop = FALSE].

Comment: One more point. Are you sure about your code? If columns represent years, than I would guess that you want to compute `rowSums` instead of colSums. That's also what your informal description of your algorithm suggests.

Comment: @stefan both of your comments were right. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to match the algorithm you describe, though it's difficult to tell from your description what the values in the first column are supposed to be.

Here's your data in matrix form:

```r
dev_costs <- t(matrix(c(1:4, 4:7, 8:9,  1:2), nrow = 4))
dev_costs
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4
#> [2,]    4    5    6    7
#> [3,]    8    9    1    2
```

We can easily make a cumulative sum of rows like this:

```
cum_dev <- t(apply(dev_costs, 1, cumsum))
```

Then an iterative loop to complete the algorithm:

```
answer <- cum_dev
for(i in seq(ncol(cum_dev))[-1])
{
  answer[,i] <- 0.4 * (cum_dev[,i] - rowSums(answer[,1:(i-1), drop = FALSE]))
}
```

Giving us

```
answer
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
#> [1,]    1  0.8 1.68 2.608
#> [2,]    4  2.0 3.60 4.960
#> [3,]    8  3.6 2.56 2.336
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It feels like there ought to be a way to skip the for loop... something like `0.4^(1:n) * (... - cumsum...)` but the details aren't coming to me right now.

Comment: @GregorThomas I know. I have a feeling there's a cool one-liner in the post...